# Python 2 does not work any more, PYTHONPATH issue?

Tags: python, path, default, ros

I use python3 normally but also some python2 with ROS. After a longer time i tried to built my ros workspace and the error I get is

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
execute_process(/home/work/py_venv/bin/python
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
"/home/work/catkin_ws/build/catkin_tools_prebuild/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
```

The first directory `/home/work/py_venv/bin/python` is a virtual environment for python3. I am not sure why it is looking there. I dont have any virtual environment activate (well on purpose at least). What I am totally missing though is the path to the standard python2 installation. Shouldnt it be there?

If I enter `echo $PYTHONPATH` in the terminal, I just get `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
I guess there is something missing? How can I set this variable correctly. Which value does it have at installation? 
I recently installed venv in python3 apart from that I am not aware of any changes I did to python since it stoped working.

Now that is a lot of questions. 
If you can answer any of them, it would be appreciated.

Edit: I know found the main problem is the prepending of the venv on the path , so that it look for the package in the python3 installation which does not contain the catkin package. How can I remove this from the path?

Comment: To see all paths where your Python searches for modules, run `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` from a Python script. PYTHONPATH is just an addition that is being inserted at the beginning of this list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove venv python path, you can do that as follow,

```
echo $PATH
export PATH=<remove unwanted path>
```

In this way, you can remove your venv python path.

Also, check this `python --version` which might be set to python3, if so change that as well.

Finally, check `PYTHONPATH` if it's not directed proper location change and try.